# Getting the value of a delegate upon clicking back?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

I have two class files. ViewController and ChooseServerView. A user clicks a cell within the ViewController class which pushes to the ChooseServerView. When a user makes a selection in ChooseServerView the value of that cell gets passed to the delegate. Now, these two views are in front of a navigation controller, so in the ChooseServerView there is a back button. When the user clicks back I want to update the cell in the first view with the new value from the delegate, make sense?

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChooseServerView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, serverUserChoice>

{
    NSString *testLocation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *testLocation;

@end
```

View Controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ChooseServerView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize testLocation;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{


   NSUserDefaults *sharedPref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   testLocation =[sharedPref stringForKey:@"defaultLocation"];

    NSLog(@"Location Chosen: %@",testLocation);


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



#pragma mark - Table View Methods


- (void) userDidChoose:(NSString *) server {

    testLocation = server;
    NSLog(@"Test Location %@", server);

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;              // Default is 1 if not implemented
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;    // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different

{

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Choose Test Location:";
            break;
        case 1:
             return @"Choose Test Type:";
        default:
            return @"Unknown";
            break;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{


    UITableViewCell *serverLocCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"serverLocation"];



    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            serverLocCell.textLabel.text = testLocation;
            serverLocCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Change";

            break;
        case 1:
            serverLocCell.textLabel.text = @"Speed Test";
            serverLocCell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Change";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return serverLocCell;

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toServerChoice" sender:self];
            break;
        case 1:
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTestType" sender:self];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
@end
```

ChooseServerView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@protocol serverUserChoice <NSObject>
@optional

- (void)userDidChoose:(NSString *) server;

@end



@interface ChooseServerView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, serverUserChoice>

{
    NSArray *serverSelection;
    NSArray *tqServerSelection;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *serverSelection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *qServerSelection;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(retain) NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <serverUserChoice> serverDelegate;

@end
```

ChooseServerView.m

```
#import "ChooseServerView.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define totalSections 2
#define standardSection 0
#define qualitySection 1

@interface ChooseServerView ()

@end

@implementation ChooseServerView;
@synthesize serverSelection;
@synthesize qServerSelection;
@synthesize lastIndexPath;
@synthesize serverDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    serverSelection = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Chicgo, IL",@"London, UK",@"San Jose, CA",@"Washington, DC", nil];
    qServerSelection = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Chicgo, IL (Q)",@"London, UK (Q)",@"San Jose, CA (Q)",@"Washington, DC (Q)", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


#pragma mark - Table View Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;              // Default is 1 if not implemented
{
    return totalSections;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;    // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different

{
    switch (section) {
        case standardSection:
            NSLog(@"Std Heading Set");
            return @"Standard Test Locations:";
            break;
        case qualitySection:
            NSLog(@"Qual Heading Set");
            return @"Quality Test Locations:";
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Section Count Error");
           return @"Section Count Error";
            break;
    }


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

{
    if (section == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Std Loc Set");
        return [serverSelection count];

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Quality Loc Set");
        return [qServerSelection count];

    }
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{


    UITableViewCell *serverLoc = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"serverSelection"];



    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case standardSection:
            serverLoc.textLabel.text = [self.serverSelection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            break;
        case qualitySection:
            serverLoc.textLabel.text = [self.qServerSelection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return serverLoc;

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *cellvalue;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cellvalue = cell.textLabel.text;
    [serverDelegate userDidChoose:cellvalue];
    NSLog(@"Cell Selected is %@",cellvalue);
    [cell setSelected:FALSE animated:TRUE];


}
@end
```

I can see the correct value gets passed to the delegate, I just don't know how to "call" that delegate/method when going back using the automatic back button implemented by the nav controller.

Any ideas would be great.

As per answer below:

Added to my ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Added to my ViewController.m

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

[image: Outlet]

Still no joy at this stage. First cell fails to update upon pressing the back button as provided by the navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are almost there.

I think the issue is that your UITableView is not being reloaded to represent the updated value of testLocation.  I don't see a reference to the UITableView that is being managed by your ViewController, first add an outlet to ViewController.m to point to this table view.

Then, add the following in your ViewController.m

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

You also need to make sure you set your ViewController as the delegate of ChooseServerViewController.  (You should rename ChooseServerView.m to ChooseServerViewController.m for clarity, as it's a view controller subclass- I've referred to it as such below)

You can set the delegate by adding a prepare for segue method in ViewController.m - something like:

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  ChooseServerViewController *viewController =  (ChooseServerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
      viewController.serverDelegate = self;
  }

I would also look into using UITableViewController for these two controller classes, since it appears that's the type of functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I've added your suggested code to no avail. My main post has been edited. Thanks

Comment: Hi Dan, found another problem, you need to set the delegate, I updated my solution with instructions on doing so.

Comment: Well I now get a Unknown ChooseServerView class in the IB file since changing the name of the file. All instances in my project are up to date and I have also double checked by build phases to make sure the new name is in there. It is and still fails. any idea?

Comment: Make sure you update the class of your ViewController in IB to ChooseServerViewController.  This is doen under the 'Identity Inspector' tab.

Comment: Actually I take that back, I have now updated it and that error has ceased

Comment: Oh and your prepare for segue addition worked also, thank you!

Comment: Awesome- great!  Happy dev'ing :)